# Everything displays correctly except for the list of products of a category

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am making a webpage using ASP.NET Core MVC. It's an online store. The issue I have is that everything displays correctly except for the list of products of a category.

Category and Product have a one-to-many relationship in the SQLite database I am working with. When I list the category, id, name, description.., works superb, but the products in that category don't show.

This is the code where I have the issue. @Model.Products is the correct call, but I tried everything, from transforming it ToList(), ToString(), or searching for the products using a foreach loop:

```
@model Packt.Shared.Category
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Category Details - " + Model.CategoryName;
}

<h2>Category Details</h2>
<hr/>
<div class=dl-horizontal>
    <dt>Category ID</dt>
    <dd>@Model.CategoryID</dd>
    <dt>Category NAme</dt>
    <dd>@Model.CategoryName</dd>
    <dt>Category description</dt>
    <dd>@Model.Description</dd>
    <dt>List of products of the category</dt>
    <dd>@Model.Products</dd> <!-Here it doesnt show a thing, not even with ToString() nor ToList(), also tried with Async->>
</div>
```

The button that launchs the code is the View button in the Index.cshtml razor page. How do I call the list of Products in the Category (1-to-many relationship)?:

```
@model NorthwindMvc.Models.HomeIndexViewModel
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Radical Change";
  string currentItem = "";
}
<div id="categories" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" 
     data-interval="3000" data-keyboard="true">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  @for (int c = 0; c < Model.Categories.Count; c++)
  {
    if (c == 0)
    {
      currentItem = "active";
    }
    else
    {
      currentItem = "";
    }
    <li data-target="#categories" data-slide-to="@c" 
      class="@currentItem"></li>
  }
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  @for (int c = 0; c < Model.Categories.Count; c++)
  {
    if (c == 0)
    {
      currentItem = "active";
    }
    else
    {
      currentItem = "";
    }
    <div class="carousel-item @currentItem">
      <img class="d-block w-100" 
src="~/images/category@(Model.Categories[c].CategoryID).jpeg" 
        alt="@Model.Categories[c].CategoryName" />
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h2>@Model.Categories[c].CategoryName</h2>
        <h3>@Model.Categories[c].Description</h3>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-primary" 
href="/Home/CategoryDetail/@Model.Categories[c].CategoryID">View</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  }
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#categories" 
    role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" 
      aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#categories" 
    role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" 
      aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <h1>Radical Change - Hairdresser</h1>
    <p class="lead">
      We've had @Model.VisitorCount visitors this month.
    </p>
    <form asp-action="ProductsThatCostMoreThan" method="get">
      <input name="price" placeholder="Enter product price" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <form asp-action="Customers" method="get">
      <input name="country" placeholder="Select a country" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
    <h2>Productos</h2>
      <div id="newspaper">
        <ul>
        @foreach (var item in @Model.Products)
        {
          <li>
            <a asp-controller="Home" 
               asp-action="ProductDetail" 
               asp-route-id="@item.ProductID">
            @item.ProductName costs
            @item.UnitPrice.Value.ToString("C")
          </a>
        </li>
      }
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: While debugging it, does the data get called from the database into the business logic? by hovering over the variables while debugging with a break point? Try debugging from the moment the data should be passed into the model at the oop level

Comment: SO,do you mean you click the `View` link and it redirects to the detail view to show the category?Could you show your controller code of `/Home/CategoryDetail` and models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you could not use `@Model.Products` to show all products' info on view.Then, your action code should use `Include` method to retrieve the navigation properties' value.
Finally,refer to my simple demo shown below.

1.Assume that you have below models:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public long CategoryID{ get; set; }
    public string CategoryName{ get; set; }
    public string Description{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products{ get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public long ProductID{ get; set; }
    public string ProductName{ get; set; }

    public long CategoryId{ get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category{ get; set; }  
}
```

2.For the `Home/CategoryDetail`, you need to use `Include` method to retrieve data:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CategoryDetail(long? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var category = await _context.Category
                                 .Include(s=>s.Products)
                                 .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.CategoryID == id);
    if (category == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(category);
}
```

3.To show `Products` info on `Category/CategoryDetail razor` view, you need to use `@foreach`:

```
@foreach(var item in Model.Products)
{ 
   <h3>@item.ProductName</h3>

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did that (step number 3) and I get this message. Products have indeed a ProductName property. NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
AspNetCore.Views_Home_CategoryDetail.ExecuteAsync() in CategoryDetail.cshtml, line 16

Comment: Products have a ProductName property,yes

'''
 public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }
        public decimal? UnitPrice { get; set; } = 0;
        public short? UnitsInStock { get; set; } = 0;
        public short? UnitsOnOrder { get; set; } = 0;
        public short? ReorderLevel { get; set; } = 0;
        public bool Discontinued { get; set; } = false;

    }
'''

Comment: @laxcivo Have you retrieved data like step2 with `Include(s=>s.Products)`?IThe error says that your `Model.Products` is null.

Comment: :D Thanks Xing Zou ! You are fantastic! This certainly made my day.

Category ID
5
Category Name
Grains/Cereals
Category Description
Breads, crackers, pasta, and cereal
Category's list of products
Gustaf's Knäckebröd
Tunnbröd
Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee
Filo Mix
Gnocchi di nonna Alice
Ravioli Angelo
Wimmers gute Semmelknödel

Comment: @laxcivo Great.Could you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you have resolved the problem?

Comment: Done. Thanks Xing Zou!